# Access application while in lock screen in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process, lockscreen

Is there any way to detect the shake when the application is in back ground in iOS ? Actually in my application i need access my application when the device is in lock screen to call some web services. Is there any way to do this to aces my application while the device is in lock screen in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer **NO** there is no way of detecting shake in background mode sorry.

Unfortunately this isn't possible in iOS 7 are lower.

Comment: you know the Nike+Running app will continue to run in the background even with the screen powered off.

Comment: The Nike+Running app has been developed between Nike and Apple they have special circumstances which we aren't allowed. As far as we as developers are concerned the Nike+Running app should be treated as if it was a normal Apple app such as itunes. If you notice the Nike+Running is packaged with the device.